# How do I create a token for the new stripe payment element as it used to be done in the old card element?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, credit-card

I am trying to use the new payment element in stripe for payment handling in my react application but the backend that was implemented requires me to send the tokenized payment details collected through stripe and send through which the backend will create a charge. The examples I have seen don't do that and all process the payment directly with stripe.  All the examples I have seen using the token doesn't seem to work for payment element and only work for the old card element.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <LinkAuthenticationElement
        id="link-authentication-element"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={paymentElementOptions} />
      
      <button className="mt-5 rounded-lg text-center flex items-center justify-center w-full px-8 py-4 bg-main text-white border-0 text-sm leading-4 font-medium sm:font-semibold sm:text-base sm:leading-[19px]" disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message" className="text-center mt-2">{message}</div>}
    </form>
```

Here is an example of the old method using card element:

```
stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
```

I have tried the following but none seems to work:

```
const cardElement = elements.getElement(cardElement);
stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        // var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        // errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        console.log(result.error.message)
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        console.log(result);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The new Stripe PaymentElements requires the use of the new PaymentIntent and PaymentMethods APIs. I invite you to refer to [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) in order to migrate from Tokens to PaymentMethods.
You need to change:

```
stripe.createToken(
  cardElement
).then(function(token) {
 // Send token to server
});
```

Into something like this:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(
 INTENT_SECRET_FROM_STEP_1,
 {
  payment_method: {card: cardElement}
 }
).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
   // Display error.message in your UI.
  } else {
   // The payment has succeeded
   // Display a success message
  }
 });
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't intend to process the payment from the frontend. The backend has to be the one to process it hence the reason for sending the token through which the backend then processes a charge. But if the token method is only available for the card element, what is the equivalent of that for the payment element and what can I send to the backend for it to process the charge instead of confirming the payment at once through stripe.confirmCardPayment

Comment: In that case you can follow this guide:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/finalize-payments-on-the-server

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest thing to it with the `payment` element:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/build-a-two-step-confirmation

In it you create the Payment Method using the `createPaymentMethod` funcion, which corresponds to your current `createToken` one.

```
  // Create the PaymentMethod using the details collected by the Payment Element
const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
   elements,
   params: {
   billing_details: {
     name: 'Jenny Rosen',
     }
   }
});
```

You can then use this Payment Method on the backend with your Payment Intent.

Still, it might not completely suit, because this flow still uses a `confirmPayment()` function on the frontend, which differs from what I'm guessing you use. I'm picturing your integration working with more of a backend confirmation, like in this legacy flow:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

Comment: I corrected it. While it's a good point, I would argue that a change in the link would suggest a change in the documentation, making the information in this post possibly outdated regardless.

Comment: Outdated information can have value, too. Consider somebody who might still be using an old version of a language or library. Links are good. The best answers usually include an answer right there, plus references. Link-only answers are considered low quality, though, to the point that the comment I left is actually a canned comment from the review system. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627) for more.

Answer (score 2):

The same situation as me. I looked at the Stripe document and see that the Stripe api createToken doesn't accept the new PaymentElement.

Then, I think currently, there is no way to create the token from the Payment Element. So, either you need to update Backend to consume paymentIntent (produced by PaymentElement) or update the Frontend to use old Stripe Card elements which are tokenizable..

Ref: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens/create_token?type=cardElement